# D3.js: Generating an X axis removes some of my point's labels, generating a Y axis removes them all

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Edit: After Cyril correctly solved the problem I noticed that simply putting the functions that generate my axes underneath the functions used to generate the labels solves the problem.

I've almost finished reading the O'Reilly book's tutorials on D3.js and made the scatter graph on the penultimate page, but when adding the following code to generate my X axis more than half of my labels disappear:

```
// Define X Axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient('bottom');
//  Generate our axis
svg.append('g')
    .call(xAxis);
```

The odd thing is that of the labels that don't disappear the 3 that stay are the bottom 3 pairs from my dataset ([85,21], [220,88], [750,150]):

```
var myData = [
                [5, 20],
                ...,
                ...,
                [85, 21],
                [220, 88],
                [750,150]
            ];
```

Here is an image of what's happening, prior to adding the axis at the top each of these points had red text labels:

[image: scatter plot]

Below is the rest of the code that generates my scatter graph, it follows the methods explained in the book almost exactly and I can't pinpoint where the error is coming from.

```
// =================
// = SCALED SCATTER GRAPH
// =================
var p = 30; // Padding
var w = 500 + p; // Width
var h = 500 + p; // Height

// SVG Canvas and point selector
var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width',w)
    .attr('height',h);

// Scales take an input value from the input domain and return
// a scaled value that corresponds to the output range
// X Scale
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(myData, function(d){
        return d[0];
    })])
    .range([p, w - (p + p)]); // With padding. Doubled so labels aren't cut off
// Y Scale
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(myData, function(d){
        return d[1];
    })])
    .range([h - p, p]); // With padding

// Radial scale
var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(myData, function(d){ return d[1];})])
    .range([2,5]);

// Define X Axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient('bottom');
//  Generate our axis
svg.append('g')
    .call(xAxis);

// Plot scaled points
svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d){
        return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d){
        return yScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr('r', function(d){
        return rScale(d[1]);
    });

// Plot all labels
svg.selectAll('text')
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .text(function(d){
        return d;
    })
    .attr('x', function(d){
        return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d){
        return yScale(d[1]);
    })
    .style('fill', 'red')
    .style('font-size',12);
```

js-fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z30cqeoo/

Comment: can you make a fiddle link?

Comment: @ozil sure thing, one moment

Comment: @ozil I've edited in a js fiddle below my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
svg.selectAll('text')
```

The x axis and y axis makes text element as ticks, so when the axis are present the above line will return array of ticks, *thus it explains why it's not displaying when axis is added*.

So the correct way would be to do something like this:

```
svg.selectAll('.text') //I am selecting those elements with class name text

svg.selectAll('.text')
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .text(function(d){
        console.log(d)
        return d;
    })
    .attr('x', function(d){
        return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d){
        return yScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr('class',"text") //adding the class
    .style('fill', 'red')
    .style('font-size',12);
```

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/w6hxzqtp/).

Comment: Thank you! I had noticed that the amount of elements along the axis directly correlated to the amount of labels shown next to points.